# certificate web doesn't accept boolean openedx

Tags: openedx

I've been trying to set up certificates on an openedx course, so far to no avail.

In [section 6.3.6.2 of the documentation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-building-and-running-a-course/en/latest/set_up_course/studio_add_course_information/studio_creating_certificates.html#enable-a-certificate) it states:

> In the Certificate Web/HTML View Enabled field, enter true.

But in my version I only have "*Certificate Web/HTML View Overrides*" and when I attempt to change  from the default of an empty dictionary {} I get the error:

> Value stored in a Dict must be None or a dict, found <type 'bool'>

The actual instructions inside the box state

> Enter course-specific overrides for the Web/HTML template parameters
> here (JSON format)

We are using a rather old version of the code, is this the reason for the discrepancy? How would I activate this?

Comment: Hi, Without knowing your Open edX version, its hard to guide. May I know your Open edX version?

Comment: hi Isanka, thanks for responding, how do I find that out if I am not an administrator? (and work in a place with an overworked and thus slow to respond IT dept) - I suspect the build is very old.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, If you are not an admin, how will you set up those certificates?